# Difference between Uint8Array and Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-management, clamp

What is the difference between `Uint8Array` and `Uint8ClampedArray` in JavaScript?
I understand that `Uint8ClampedArray` is used with canvas for pixel manipulations. Why is that and what is the benefit?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Looking at the examples for [Uint8ClampedArray](http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8ClampedArray) and [Uint8Array](http://www.javascripture.com/Uint8Array), it looks like the difference is how values are treated when assigned.

If you are trying to set one element to a clamped array to any value outside of the range `0-255`, it will simply default to 0 or 255 (depending on whether the value is smaller or larger). A normal `Uint8Array` array just takes the first 8 bit of the value.

Examples:

```
var x = new Uint8ClampedArray([17, -45.3]);
console.log(x[0]); // 17
console.log(x[1]); // 0
console.log(x.length); // 2

var x = new Uint8Array([17, -45.3]);
console.log(x[0]); // 17
console.log(x[1]); // 211
console.log(x.length); // 2
```

Comment: Note also that `Uint8Array([0.9])` is `[0]`, but `Uint8ClampedArray([0.9])` is `[1]`, ie. the clamped version uses rounding, but the basic version uses floor.

Comment: The OP mentioned this was used for pixel values in the canvas, is this a shortcut for saturated arithmetic?

Comment: @Felix, So `Uint8Array` is more performant because no bounds checking need be done?

Comment: Also [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) is created from an `Uint8ClampedArray`

Comment: I think Uint8Array would be faster - unless you were using the clamping features for graphics, which maybe faster in that case.

Comment: Neither the answer, nor the examples give a clue why and in what cases that behavior of `Uint8ClampedArray` could be beneficial.

Comment: @llya These are for image/video/audio process. The main feature is: it never overflow/underflow.  When you are trying to increase the brightness in an image: max brightness (255)+1 should give 255, not overflow to zero.